# WCF service with multiple webHttpBinding bindings fails in visual studio test client

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012, wcf-4

I have a service with four endpoints defined, the configuration looks like this:

```
  <service name="Systembolaget.Services.ButikService" behaviorConfiguration="default">
    <endpoint
        address="xml"
        binding="webHttpBinding"
        behaviorConfiguration="xml"
        contract="Systembolaget.Contracts.Butiker.IButikService" />

    <endpoint
        address="json"
        binding="webHttpBinding"
        behaviorConfiguration="json"
        contract="Systembolaget.Contracts.Butiker.IButikService" />

    <endpoint
        address="soap"
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        contract="Systembolaget.Contracts.Butiker.IButikService"
        bindingConfiguration="default"/>

    <endpoint
        address="mex"
        binding="mexHttpBinding"
        contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="xml">
      <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml" defaultBodyStyle="Bare"></webHttp>
    </behavior>

    <behavior name="json">
      <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" defaultBodyStyle="Bare"></webHttp>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="default">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

When using the service with any of the end points it all works fine. However I can't use the test client in Visual Studio 2012 if both the xml and the json end point exists. If I comment out one or the other, the client works, if I keep both in the config file I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from `http://localhost:52832/VarugruppService.svc` If this is a  Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have  enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at `http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455`.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   URI: `http://localhost:52832/VarugruppService.svc`
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: `http://localhost:52832/VarugruppService.svc`.
>   There was no endpoint listening  at `http://localhost:52832/VarugruppService.svc` that could accept the message. This is often caused by  an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>   The remote  server returned an error: (404) Not Found.HTTP GET Error
>   URI: `http://localhost:52832/VarugruppService.svc`
>   There was an error downloading  '`http://localhost:52832/VarugruppService.svc`'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes - the WCF Test Client is for **SOAP** bindings only - anything **but** `webHttpBinding`. The REST-based `webHttpBinding` can be tested directly with a browser or with a tool like FIddler

Comment: Yes, I know that and I do have a soap binding that does works as long as I don't have more than one webHttpBinding defined for the service.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a separate binding configuration for each webHttpBindng:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="xmlWebBinding">
    </binding>
    <binding name="jsonWebBinding">
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>

</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="Systembolaget.Services.ButikService" behaviorConfiguration="default">
    <endpoint
        address="xml"
        binding="webHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="xmlWebBinding"
        behaviorConfiguration="xml"
        contract="Systembolaget.Contracts.Butiker.IButikService" />

    <endpoint
        address="json"
        binding="webHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="jsonWebBinding"
        behaviorConfiguration="json"
        contract="Systembolaget.Contracts.Butiker.IButikService" />

    <endpoint
        address="soap"
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        contract="Systembolaget.Contracts.Butiker.IButikService"
        bindingConfiguration="default"/>

    <endpoint
        address="mex"
        binding="mexHttpBinding"
        contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="xml">
      <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml" defaultBodyStyle="Bare"></webHttp>
    </behavior>

    <behavior name="json">
      <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" defaultBodyStyle="Bare"></webHttp>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="default">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Credit to the answerer at the bottom of this forum:

http://tiku.io/questions/1554725/how-can-basichttpbinding-webhttpbinding-mexhttpbinding-endpoints-coexist-in-o